# apply custom function on pandas dataframe on a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Suppose you have a dataframe with 1000 closing prices.
You want to apply a risk calculation function (let's say VaR) named `compute_var()` on last 90 closing prices, on a rolling basis.
How would you do it? I presume with `apply()`:

```
def compute_var(df):
       return do_calculations_on(df[-90:])

def compute_rolling_var(self):
       self.var = self.closing.apply(compute_var)
```

Problem is that `.apply` only passes 1 day closing to compute_var, and not a dataframe. So it gives an error.

The only working solution I found is with iteration-style algo (.iterrow()): I pass the iteration index to `compute_var` and it crops the closing dataframe `self.closing[:i]` before performing calculation on the last 90 rows, then it populates the df.var dataframe via `.loc(i) = computer_var_value`.

I suspect there is a better way.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`rolling_apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html#pandas.rolling_apply) it accepts a window param

Comment: Seems that `rolling_apply` has been deprecated in favor of [`rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is apply_rolling as underlined by EdChum + min_periods adjustment

Problem came from a few `NaN` values in input data, and `min_periods=None` by default, which reacts as if *no* `NaN` value is allowed in your window (90 days here). 
Seems very counter-intuitive to me, but setting `min_periods=1` resolved my issue.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please provide an answer and accept it, rather than editing the solution into the question.